# Vibrate iPhone every second

Tags: iphone, applications, vibrate

Is there an app I can use to vibrate my iPhone once every second continuously?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way.

Here's how on the iPhone (with pictures):

1. Download [Pro Metronome by EUMLab](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id477960671)
2. Use the large scroll wheel in the center to set the tempo to 60 BPM.
3. Press the button in the bottom left labelled "4/4"
   [image: Pro Metronome]
4. From there, subtract the "beat" option until you see "1/4"
5. Tap the top area of the screen to go back to the main page.
   [image: Pro Metronome]
6. Tap the pink rectangle in the top left until it is grayed out. This will prevent the phone from making a noise.
7. Tap the settings icon in the top left.
   [image: Pro Metronome]
8. Enable the "Vibrate" option.
9. Go back to the main screen by tapping the right side of the screen.
   [image: Pro Metronome]
10. Press the play button! The phone should vibrate every second until you close the app or the battery dies.